# How to query a DocumentRefrence in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in firebase Firestore and when i tried to write this code with Firestore I faced a problem.

```
DatabaseReference mDisplayData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(postKey);
                com.google.firebase.database.Query firstQuery = mDisplayData.limitToFirst(20);
                firstQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            String nameData = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String statusData = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String imageData = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                            userViewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),nameData,statusData,imageData);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
```

the problem was in this line of code :

```
 Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(postKey).collection(null);
```

what i want to do is to create a firestore query but i want to stop only in postkey refrence the thing that is not possible what should i do.
please help and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`firstQuery` in the following line of code:

```
Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(postKey).collection(null);
```

Is of type `Firestore Query` and is not of type `Firebase real-time database Query`. So there is no way in which you can call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` on such an object. What you are actually trying to do, is to use code that can get the data from Firebase real-time database on Firestore query, which obviously is not possible.

To solve this, you need to use a `get()` call on your `firstQuery` object and then attach a listener. But first I recommend you read the official documentation regarding [getting data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Comment: yes, yes i know that the query here is a firebase.firestore query and not a database.query and this not the problem. the problem is how to get only the postkey with firestore.query. thank you for the answer.

Comment: Using the code you have shared,  you'll never be able to get anything from a Firestore database. Share your database structure and please indicate what exactly you want to get.

Comment: Not yet, I sorry i didn't see your question, I think that i have to change my database stucture to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?